# Core data not retaining older values

Tags: swift, core-data

When I save to Core Data and then try to read from it, only the most recently saved value is retained.
The rest are `nil` when I try to print them out.

In my `.xcdatamodeld`, my entity is named `CD_Cookbook` and it has an attribute of `name`.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
func newCookbook(cookbook: String) {
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "CD_Cookbook", in: managedContext)!
    let item = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)
    item.setValue(cookbook, forKey: "name")
    do {
        try managedContext.save()
    }
    catch {
        print("did not save cookbook name to core data", error)
    }

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "CD_Cookbook")
    do {
        let cd = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        print(cd)
    }
    catch {
        print("Failed to fetch cookbook names from Core Data", error)
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with rest are nil, are the oldest objects nil or have some property been set to nil? Either way I don’t think the problem lies in the code you have posted.

Comment: What is `nil`? Share the log of `print(cd)`. What other entities/relations does `CD_Cookbook` have? ...elaborate

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "CD_Cookbook")
```

Do this instead:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "CD_Cookbook")
```

Comment: Add an explanation of what you have done and how it solves the issue to help the OP and future readers who are reading this because they face a similar issue